# only show months on chart.js x-axis

Tags: charts

I have some time-data that I'd like to show with Chart.js. The graph is displayed correctly, but instead of having invididual days on the x-axis, I'd like to see the months at most. I tried setting `"unit"`/`"minUnit"` like

```json
{
  "config": {
    "type": "line",
    "data": {
      "labels": [
        "2020-01-26",
        [...]
        "2022-01-02",
      ],
      "datasets": [...]
    },
    "options": {
      "elements": { "point": { "radius": 0 } },
      "scales": { "xAxes": [{ "type": "time", "time": { "unit": "month" } }] }
    }
  }
}
```

but this still gives

[image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you don't need a list `[]` for the options. The following works well:

```js
"x": {                                                                             
  "type": "time",                                                                  
  "time": { "unit": "month" },                                                     
  "grid": { "display": false }                                                     
}
```